# How to allow & symbol when using htmlspecialchars()

Tags: php, laravel-5, htmlspecialchars

I am using `htmlspecialchars()` on my site to display status post from users.
The status post is being saved to my database and pulled to show in their timeline.

I'm using laravel 5.3

The problem is if someone post something like: `Netflix & Chill`, this turns into `Netflix &amp; Chill`

How can i still use `htmlspecialchars()` so that I can keep my site safe, but still show the proper text instead of turning even `&` symbol into `&amp;`

Comment: HTML would interpret `&amp;` and display it as `&`, or are you experiencing otherwise? Perhaps you're using this function twice on the string? Are you using this on output, or input into the database?

Answer (score 1):

It should display the proper text.

The most common reason I've seen for what you're describing is double encoding. (Passing the string through `htmlspecialchars` twice.) For example, with

```
$str = 'Netflix & Chill';
```

If you use `echo htmlspecialchars($str)`, you'll see 'Netflix & Chill' in the browser. But if you use `echo htmlspecialchars(htmlspecialchars($str));` instead, you'll see the escaped ampersand in the browser. (If you view the page source, it's actually `Netflix &amp;amp; Chill`.)

You may be inadvertently doing this if you're using a template that escapes the output automatically. I noticed you tagged the question with Laravel, and blade templates do this. See here in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#displaying-data):

> Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlspecialchars function to prevent XSS attacks.

If that's what you're using to display your data, you shouldn't use `htmlspecialchars` before you send the values to the template.

Comment: It could also be that the inputted data already has `&amp;` in it. You can disable PHP from double encoding with the `$double_encode` param. http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: @Charles good point. I wonder if the auto-escaping in the templates uses that param.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I'm doing this in my view {!!$linkify->process(nl2br(htmlspecialchars($status->body)))!!}

Answer (score 1):

`htmlspecialchars` converts a raw ASCII character into it's HTML entity. This means that they will still be rendered correctly on the page (i.e. a `<` symbol will still appear as `<` on the page), but will not have any special meaning for HTML.

Thus, in the ***database***, they will appear as [entity codes](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp), but when rendered onto the ***page***, users will be able to see them as the initial characters that they typed.

If you need to preserve the characters in the database (I am not sure why you would need to), you could look into replacing them with [homoglyphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoglyph), as preserving their appearance in the database and the protection of your HTML is not possible if you are simply using `htmlspecialchars`.